# Can I get more information about "implicit dependencies" in Gradle 7.0?

Tags: gradle

[ Updated 16 April 2021, see reproducible test case below.]

I started converting a small Gradle build to Gradle 7.0. It says:

```
> Task :junit_xsd
Execution optimizations have been disabled for task ':junit_xsd' to ensure correctness due to the following reasons:
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: '/Users/ndw/Projects/xproc/test-suite/build'. Reason: Task ':git_log_shorter' uses this output of task ':junit_xsd' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.0/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
```

I've looked at the documentation link and it wasn't very informative (to me).

The two tasks in question are, AFAICT, unrelated. `junit_xsd` is a simple copy task:

```
task junit_xsd(type: Copy) {
  from "src/main/schema/"
  into "build/"
  include "*.xsd"
}
```

The `git_log_shorter` task is a bit harder to describe. It's a custom task that runs a process I wrote.

```
task git_log_shorter(dependsOn: ["git_log_summary"], type: XMLCalabashTask) {
  inputs.file "tools/xsl/shorter-log.xsl"
  inputs.file "build/git-log-summary.xml"
  outputs.file "build/git-log-shorter.xml"
  input("source", "build/git-log-summary.xml")
  output("result", "build/git-log-shorter.xml")
  pipeline "tools/xpl/run-xslt.xpl"
  option("stylesheet", "../xsl/shorter-log.xsl")
}
```

But it doesn't read any `xsd` files, so I can't work out why Gradle thinks there's an implicit dependency on `junit_xsd`.

I mean, I suppose it reads out of the `build` directory, but I have lots of tasks that create and use temporary files from the `build` directory. I'll be a little shocked if *any* task that reads from the `build` directory is now implicitly dependent on *every* task that writes to it.

If that is the case, what's the proposed solution for temporary files?

The `git_log_summary` task, for example, is the task that writes `build/git-log-summary.xml` and I have an explicit dependency for that task.

Am I overlooking something obvious?

Here's a test case that doesn't involve any extension steps. Running the `doall` task produces the warning:

```
task doall(dependsOn: ["copyA", "pointless_gzip"]) {
  // nop
}

task copyA(type: Copy) {
  from "src/main/data/"
  into "${buildDir}"
  include "*.xsd"
}

task pointless_tar(type: Exec) {
  outputs.file "${buildDir}/pointless.tar"
  commandLine 'tar', '-cf', "${buildDir}/pointless.tar", 'src'
  doFirst {
    mkdir("${buildDir}")
  }
}

task pointless_gzip(dependsOn: ["pointless_tar"], type: Exec) {
  inputs.file "${buildDir}/pointless.tar"
  outputs.file "${buildDir}/pointless.tar.gz"
  commandLine 'gzip', '-k', "${buildDir}/pointless.tar"
}
```

Comment: Test case repostiory: https://github.com/ndw/test-case-for-stackoverflow-67114825

Comment: I got a nice explanation of this situation over on the Gradle forums, https://discuss.gradle.org/t/gradle-7-0-seems-to-take-an-overzealous-approach-to-inter-task-dependencies/39656/2